# What do NRAM cells look like?

Tags: memory, non-volatile-memory

**Note:** I don't have any electrical engineering experience, so I'd like to apologize for my bad vocabulary about this subject.

I'm currently exploring the memory world and stumbled across [NRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-RAM) which got my interest.

Now I encountered two different images of what an NRAM-cell looks like:

1. From the general [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-RAM#/media/File:NRAM_fabric.png)
2. From [wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/File:nram_cell.svg)

May I ask which of those two images is correct or are both actually correct but are showing two different things?

Bonus question: Do you also have any other sources to learn more about NRAM?

Comment: the wikichip one looks more detailed, but essentially the same. What difference do you mean? But I don't think it is a super mature tech so there could be variations. If you want to learn more, you should contact Nantero. They also have some white papers on their homepage